# Launching ViewController as sheet from windowDidLoad

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, viewcontroller

I'm trying to show a storyboard as a sheet right after the window has loaded.

```
override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()
    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Init"), bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialController() as! NSViewController
    self.window!.contentViewController?.presentViewControllerAsSheet(controller)
}
```

Unfortunately, the sheet is shown out of position and behind the window.
When I run the same code inside a button, everything works fine.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29LLJ.png)

How do i correctly show a storyboard sheet after loading a window?

Comment: I am not a mac developer but I think that `windowDidLoad` is not the correct place to show other windows. Probably you should wait until the given window is shown before presenting other windows, probably in `viewDidAppear` of the `contentViewController`.

Comment: @Sulthan You're right, thanks - i've been used the wrong func in the window lifecycle.
Running the code in `viewDidAppear` of the `contentViewController` does work!
(I'd approve your awnser if you post it as one)

Comment: Posted an answer then. It was just a guess because I don't know the MacOS ecosystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have more knowledge of the iOS ecosystem but I suppose that you should show new windows only after the origin window has been shown. `windowDidLoad` is called when the view has been loaded, not when it has been shown.

Therefore, you should probably put your code into `viewDidAppear` of the `contentViewController`.